Continued Issues with "No Space Left on Device" Error Despite Ample Storage on Google Drive and Colab Pro
I am facing a issue while trying to download the dataset for the RSNA STR Pulmonary Embolism Detection competition to my Google Drive using Kaggle and Google Colab Pro. Despite having 2TB of available storage on Google Drive and being a Colab Pro user, the download process frequently gets stuck and shows error

OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Could someone please provide further insights or solutions to resolve this issue?
Or an idea for another platform to download to Drive?
the code on colab:
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

!pip install kaggle

!mkdir ~/.kaggle
!cp /content/kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/
!chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json

!kaggle competitions download -c rsna-str-pulmonary-embolism-detection -p /content/drive/MyDrive/rsna_data

